# Regex number range prasing

Tags: regex, integer, range, user-agent

I am trying to parse out a specific number range, and can't seem to get it right.  I am looking to extract specific browser versions from user agent strings.  For example, I want to parse Chrome 1-42 and Firefox 1-40, but I can't figure out the syntax.

What I have so far is this, which kind of works, but it grabs the first number it sees and doesn't respect the 2 digit range:

Gecko..Chrome/([1-9].|[1-4][1-2].)

Sample:

Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.1847.137 Safari/537.36
Firefox 29: Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:29.0) Gecko/29.0 Firefox/23.0
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:29.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/29.0

Any ideas?  TIA.

Comment: Very unclear: do you want to match and capture `34` and `38` here? And that number must be from 1 to 42? Then, try [`Gecko\)\s+Chrome/([23][0-9]|4[0-2]|[1-9])`](https://regex101.com/r/wQ1nI5/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
((?:(?:Mozilla\/(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|40))|(?:Chrome\/(?:[1-9]|[1-3][0-9]|4[0-3])))\.[^ ]+)
```

Is this what you would like? /Edited/
Demo:
    https://regex101.com/r/gH1nU9/2

Answer (score 0):

Because regex is text matching only and number are treated as text, to do something like 1 to 41 you would have to something like this:

```
\b[1-9]\b|\b[1-3][0-9]\b|4[0-2]\b
```

This is matching 1 to 9 or 10 to 39 or 40 to 42. I have added the boundries `\b` so that nothing except thes numbers are matched.